# Mist maker using a piezoelectric disk. How does this circuit make oscillations?

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, piezo

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOZi3QnnDCo) video of Great Scott has been referenced many times here.  The schematic he uses is this:

[image: Schematic used by Great Scott in his video]

The piezoelectric disk requires high oscillating voltage to work.  This combination of L, C, MOSFET and the PWM signal generated by the 555 timer generates an oscillating voltage.

I don't understand how it produces the oscillating voltage.

I have tried to understand it as an LC tank circuit, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think the same schematic has been asked here before. Have you tried to find it?

Comment: `I can't figure it out` - what **can** you figure out?

Comment: R1 and C2 choose the frequency, the 555 is the oscillator. Tune R1 to hit SP1's resonance. L1 is likely to be just an "RF choke", though it may be resonant with (C1 and SP1 in series).

Answer (score 6):

The oscillation isn't from an LC tank circuit.

The 555 timer IC generates the driving signal.  It is wired as an oscillator.  The frequency it generates is set by C2 and R1.

The MOSFET and the inductor are used to make a high voltage to drive the piezo transducer.

The 555 triggers the MOSFET on and off.  When it is on, current flows through the inductor.  When the MOSFET is off, the inductor tries to keep the current flowing, so it raises the voltage until it can force current through the transducer.

I expect L1 and C1 were chosen (in consideration of the capacitance of the transducer) to be resonant at about the resonant frequency of the transducer.  That would help increase the voltage to the transducer.

Comment: "So it raises the voltage until it can force current through the transducer."
What path does the current follow? I get that when the mosfet closes there is a high voltage at the junction point between L1, C1 and the mosfet, but then what happens? How does is pass thru SP1?